# display price from two tables without eliminate products

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this Query:

```
 select ItemName,FrgnName,OnHand,Price as Regular_Price from ITM1, OITM 
 where exists
 (select null from OSCN 
 where oitm.ItemCode=oscn.ItemCode
 and itm1.ItemCode=oscn.ItemCode
 and oscn.CardCode='test'
 and itm1.PriceList=2)
```

this query is to get all the products linked to a certain customer with regular price (7 products).
Now I want to add fourth table (sprecial_prices table) which has only 6 products with special price for this customer.

the problem is if i add the special_price table to the query my result will be **6 products** and i want to display all customer's items with both prices even though one of them is 0.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your query can be re-written in SQL92 syntax this way:

```
select
   i.ItemName,FrgnName,o.OnHand,i.Price
from
  ITM1 i
  inner join OITM o on i.ItemCode = o.ItemCode
  inner join OSCN os on o.ItemCode = os.ItemCode
where
  o.CardCode = 'test'
  and i.PriceList = 2
```

To add the 4th table you want to use a left join so that all records are shown even if there are no results in the 4th table:

```
select
   i.ItemName,FrgnName,o.OnHand,i.Price
from
  ITM1 i
  inner join OITM o on i.ItemCode = o.ItemCode
  inner join OSCN os on o.ItemCode = os.ItemCode
  left join special_price sp on o.ItemCode = sp.ItemCode  --or whatever column joins to special_price
where
  o.CardCode = 'test'
  and i.PriceList = 2
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but you select i.ItemName,FrgnName,OnHand,Price from ITM1 and only price exists in this table
name, onhand exist in OITM table not ITM1 
I tried but not working !

Comment: You didn't specify which columns went with which table, so I left off the alias for those. Please specify your error.

Comment: @JosephB, no errors. just the tables names were messed up.

Comment: @paqogomez, thanks for your answer. I edited the answer with the correct tables.
thanks for your help.

Comment: @Samira, great glad it is working for you!  Note that the community rejected your edit, in future, add more information to your original post, or post comments on the answer to clarify information you missed in the post.